# Post Method not Working in Angular10 + ASP.NET back end

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I can't figure out why my POST method isn't working. Everything is fine with the API and I think CORS is working fine as well since I can get the data from the database on my browser via Angular.

I'm finding hard to debug as the error response doesn't contain a lot of clear information (at least I couldn't find it).

[image]

I'm also console.logging the data from the form on my browser which means the data is being sent correctly.

[image]

Here's the post on the API:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Record> AddRecord(Record record)
        {
            _context.Records.Add(record);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
```

Here's the form

```
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
        name="Date" 
        #Date="ngModel" 
        [(ngModel)]="service.formData.Date" 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Date"
        required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
        name="Name" 
        #Name="ngModel" 
        [(ngModel)]="service.formData.Name" 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Name"
        required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
        name="Value" 
        #Value="ngModel" 
        [(ngModel)]="service.formData.Value" 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Value"
        required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
        name="Category" 
        #Category="ngModel" 
        [(ngModel)]="service.formData.Category" 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Category"
        required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input 
        name="Type" 
        #Type="ngModel" 
        [(ngModel)]="service.formData.Type" 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Type"
        required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

here's the component:

```
export class RecordDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public service: RecordDetailService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null)
    form.resetForm();

    this.service.formData = {
      Date : "",
      Name: "",
      Value: 0 , 
      Category: "",
      Type: ""
    }
  }

  onSubmit (form: NgForm) {
    this.service.postRecordDetail(form.value).subscribe(
      res=> {
        console.log("Deu Certo Porra")
        debugger
        this.resetForm(form);
      },
      err=> {
        debugger
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Here's the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RecordDetail } from './record-detail.model';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http"

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecordDetailService {
  formData: RecordDetail
  readonly rootURL = 'http://localhost:5001/api'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postRecordDetail(formData: RecordDetail) {
    console.log(formData)
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL+'/records', formData)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools to get the exact payload being submitted (and share it in your question).

Comment: @mjwills I've added a couple of pictures with more info

Comment: Try converting the form input fields into an instance of a type/interface, update your service to accept this type. This will keep the service clean.

Comment: Also, use postman to manually validate the api is working. Along with validating options preflight works as expected.

Comment: I found the problem. It was here: "readonly rootURL = 'http://localhost:5001/api'" ... should be 'https'. two hours of my life lost on this  :(